# LINQ Join multiple tables - Return all matches even if null

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 3 tables (teams, managers, managers_teams). It is a many to many relationship. I want to return all teams whether a manager has been assigned to the team or not. 
I have this for the time being and it does not work. I followed this [guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3169/understanding-linq-to-join-multiple-tables-where-null-match-are-expected/) but I think I am missing something.

```
from t in teams
join mt in managers_teams on t.id equals mt.team_id into grp_t_mt
join m in managers on mt.manager_id equals m.id // stuck here. I tried many things here
from mt in grp_t_mt.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new tvVM
{
    id = t.id,
    name = t.teamname,
    manager = m.name
}
```

- Table Teams [id, teamname]
- Table Managers [id, name]
- Table managers_teams [id, team_id,    manager_id]

I want to get the id, teamname from table team with the name from table managers even if records do not match.

The solution [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq) does not work for me. I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: If you get a nullReferenceException you are doing something wrong... a left join **is** what you need, you simply need to do it right.

Comment: If you take out the stuck here line does it work (not the results, does it compile)?  Shouldn't you need another into statement in the stuck here line and use "from m" instead of "from mt"?